# momentjs to check whether time value is present or not

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can we check with moment JS whether value has time present or not.

like, 2021-01-01 // no time.  2021-02-05 01:03:11 PM //time present.

Comment: Length of string date with no time is 10...does that help? Not sure that moment is the right tool for this. Using regex might make more sense. What is your actual use case?

Comment: yeah, just in case anything built in momentjs. instead of string operation ? Use case is, based on date, format particular format and if its date-time then format another way.

Comment: Probably not because when you pass a string to moment it recommends you also pass the format also like `moment('2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: There's a place you can check: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Ok. Then, I have to check with string length way.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse custom date formats using Momentjs.

Your parser should be `YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:s A`

Moment has a function to check if certain moment object is valid so in combination with those two things we can do something like:

```
if(moment('2019-02-05 01:03:11 PM', 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:s A').isValid())
```

If date time string in correct format is provided and moment successfully initializes it's object, `isValid` function will return true and thus you are sure that both date and time is passed in correct format.

For more info about custom date time format strings you can check this out:  https://thecodebarbarian.com/formatting-javascript-dates-with-moment-js.html

Edit: I just saw in the comments of your post that you plan on checking string length. Do not do that. It is not secure and it can (and will) produce false positives very often. The way I posted is much better because it will accept just certain format and it must be valid date.